# Get the second image in the carousel slider JQuery

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am using carousel from http://web.enavu.com/demos/carousel.html . I want the first left image to be opacity: 1, the rest opacity: 0.5. :)

Anyone can help?

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //move he last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks to slide left he will be able to see the last item.
    $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last')); 


    //when user clicks the image for sliding right        
    $('#right_scroll img').click(function(){

        //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
        var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

        //calculae the new left indent of the unordered list
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;

        //make the sliding effect using jquery's animate function '
        $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

            //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
            $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first')); 

            //and get the left indent to the default -210px
            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});
        }); 
    });

  });
 </script>

 <div id='carousel_container'>
<div id='carousel_inner'>
    <ul id='carousel_ul'>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='item1.png' /></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='item2.png' /></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='item3.png' /></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='item4.png' /></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='item5.png' /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @oMiKeY yes, some css styling like set opacity to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery, grab the center item with

```
var middle = $('li').get(2);
```

which will always return the center item. Just after this query run

```
$(middle).css('opacity, .2'); // adjust the translucency of the image
```

add `onclick="changeMiddle()"` to each of the arrow buttons to trigger this function:

```
function changeMiddle()
{
    var middle = $('li').get(2); // fetch middle image
    $('li').css('opacity', '1');  // correct previous transparencies
    $(middle).css('opacity', '.2');   // make middle image transparent
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function . I think it's referring to middle.css('opacity', '.2'); , it can't get middle.

Comment: I forgot, whenever you use '.get(#)' it takes you out of jQuery, so you have to rewrap it. Editing now... - there, I re-jQuerified middle in the statement you mentioned.